# Android JDBC Connectivity problems

Tags: java, android, mysql, jdbc, phpmyadmin

I am trying to connect to my website's MySQL database, and I have no knowledge of PHP so I decided to use JDBC. I followed some video tutorials (non JDBC) and I used their steps. I skipped the MAMP step though because I am not hosting the server off of my PC. It is being hosted locally because it is going to be a larger website.

So I have this code entered in my Login Activity (first screen you see):

```
Connection connection = null;
    Statement statement = null;

    String username = "username";
    String password = "password";

    String dbURL = "jdbc:mysql://216.26.176.52:3306/lifesizefoto";

    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL, username, password);
        statement = connection.createStatement();
        System.out.println("Connected.");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException error) {
        System.out.println("Cannot connect");
    } catch (SQLException error) {
        System.out.println("Error: " + error.getMessage());
    } catch (InstantiationException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (connection != null) { try {connection.close();} catch (SQLException ignore) {} }
        if (statement != null) { try {statement.close();} catch (SQLException ignore) {} }
    }
```

I have tried many variations to the .getConnection() statement, but I can't figure it out. I have also contacted the website host and he took down all firewalls for my IP and even opened up a special port for the app.

When I run my app, I get this error:

```
    01-09 18:59:32.769: I/System.out(14178): Error: Communications link failure
01-09 18:59:32.769: I/System.out(14178): The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
```

I would appreciate any help. Thank you in advanced!

Answer (score 0):

Two thoughts:

- It's unlikely that your web site's MySQL server is bound to an external interface - it's likely only listening on the localhost interface. Your hosting provider should be able to confirm / possibly fix that for you.
- Trying to connect a mobile app directly to a server database is probably not going to work well in the long run - I'd suggest that you either figure out how to write a server-side app (for your mobile app to connect to) in PHP, or find another language that your host supports, and do it in that.

Comment: I was going to do PHP in the first place, but this version is only BETA and I have not idea how to code in PHP, so I am going to learn that for the next version.

Comment: If I connect to the host's SSL VPN, would that place me on their localhost?

Comment: probably, but you'll need to check the specifics with your hosting provider.